# Unable to select rows by subquery

Tags: mysql, select

DB STRUCTURE

```
    mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM Users;
    +----+-------+--------+
    | ID | NAME  | ROLE   |
    +----+-------+--------+
    |  1 | User1 | admin  |
    |  2 | User2 | admin  |
    |  3 | User3 | normal |
    |  4 | User4 | normal |
    |  5 | User5 | normal |
    +----+-------+--------+
    5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT * 
    -> FROM Articles;
    +----+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+
    | ID | TITLE        | CONTENT                       | CATEGORY_ID | USER_ID |
    +----+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+
    |  1 | Joke of day  | Lorem IPUSM lOPECV FEEWFVV    |           1 |       1 |
    |  2 | Politics     | Modi kejriwal pappu           |           3 |       4 |
    |  3 | 1000 rs note | lorme kekroek jjfojf kofkkfok |           2 |       4 |
    |  4 | bank         | deposit fmoent                |           1 |       5 |
    +----+--------------+-------------------------------+-------------+---------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT * 
    -> FROM Comments;
    +----+---------+---------+------------+
    | ID | COMMENT | USER_ID | ARTICLE_ID |
    +----+---------+---------+------------+
    |  1 | HAHA    |       2 |          2 |
    |  2 | LOL     |       2 |          4 |
    |  3 | sad     |       1 |          3 |
    |  4 | okay    |       3 |          1 |
    |  5 | ok      |       5 |          2 |
    |  6 | hmm     |       4 |          1 |
    +----+---------+---------+------------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

======================================================================

I want to select all articles and their associated comments which are written by User3.

Did this by joins

```
    mysql> SELECT Articles.*, GROUP_CONCAT(COMMENT) AS Comments
        -> FROM Articles, Comments, Users
        -> WHERE Articles.USER_ID = Users.ID
        ->     AND Articles.ID = Comments.ARTICLE_ID
        ->     AND Users.NAME = 'User3'
        -> GROUP BY ID;
    +----+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+
    | ID | TITLE  | CONTENT              | CATEGORY_ID | USER_ID | Comments      |
    +----+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+
    |  6 | Virat  | Kohli scores Century |           2 |       3 | Wow,Wonderful |
    |  7 | Floods | Floods in USA        |           1 |       3 | SAD           |
    +----+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+---------------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Unable to do this by subquery

```
      mysql> SELECT Articles.*, Comments.* 
             FROM Articles, Comments
             WHERE Articles.USER_ID = (
                 SELECT @user_id:= ID
                 FROM Users
                 WHERE NAME = 'User3'
                 )
               AND
               Comments.ARTICLE_ID IN (
                 SELECT ID
                 FROM Articles
                 Where USER_ID = @user_id
                 );
      +----+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+----+-----------+---------+------------+
      | ID | TITLE  | CONTENT              | CATEGORY_ID | USER_ID | ID | COMMENT   | USER_ID | ARTICLE_ID |
      +----+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+----+-----------+---------+------------+
      |  6 | Virat  | Kohli scores Century |           2 |       3 |  9 | Wow       |       1 |          6 |
      |  7 | Floods | Floods in USA        |           1 |       3 |  9 | Wow       |       1 |          6 |
      |  6 | Virat  | Kohli scores Century |           2 |       3 | 10 | Wonderful |       2 |          6 |
      |  7 | Floods | Floods in USA        |           1 |       3 | 10 | Wonderful |       2 |          6 |
      |  6 | Virat  | Kohli scores Century |           2 |       3 | 11 | SAD       |       4 |          7 |
      |  7 | Floods | Floods in USA        |           1 |       3 | 11 | SAD       |       4 |          7 |
      +----+--------+----------------------+-------------+---------+----+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It happen because You didn't equal Articles.ID = Comments.ARTICLE_ID in your second Query.

Your query is look like, use join without on clause. In these situations MySQL try to cross join all rows.

Correct query is:

```
SELECT Articles.*, Comments.*
FROM Articles, Comments
WHERE Articles.USER_ID = (
SELECT @user_id:= ID
FROM Users
WHERE NAME = 'User4'
) AND
 Comments.ARTICLE_ID IN (
SELECT ID
FROM Articles
WHERE USER_ID = @user_id
) and Articles.id = Comments.article_id
```

But if you want result of second query just same as first query use this:

```
SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`comment`) AS Comments from
(
SELECT Articles.*, Comments.`comment`
FROM Articles, Comments
WHERE Articles.USER_ID = (
SELECT @user_id:= ID
FROM Users
WHERE NAME = 'User4'
) AND
Comments.ARTICLE_ID IN (
SELECT ID
FROM Articles
WHERE USER_ID = @user_id
) and Articles.id = Comments.article_id
) as t
GROUP BY id;
```